# HTML 5 Radio Buttons Required Message Wrong Position

Tags: html, forms, radio-button, materialize, required

I am trying to make two groups of radio buttons required. When I test it, it shows up on the far left rather than under the buttons. I have tried removing the materialize grid around it, and still nothing.
[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOT8h.png)

My code is here

```
<div class="row">
                    <!-- What kind of change do you want -->
                    <div class="col s1" id="ChangeType">
                        <input name="group2" type="radio" id="Update" value="Update" class="Check" required/>
                        <label for="Update">Update</label>
                        <input name="group2" type="radio" id="delete" value="Delete" class="Check" />
                        <label for="delete">Delete</label>
                        <input name="group2" type="radio" id="Add" value="Add" />
                        <label for="Add">Add</label>
                    </div>
                    <!-- What do you want to change -->
                    <div class="col s2">
                        <input name="group3" type="radio" id="MenuLink" value="Menu Link" required/>
                        <label for="MenuLink">Menu Link</label>
                        <input name="group3" type="radio" id="Hotlist" value="Hotlist" />
                        <label for="Hotlist">Hot List Item</label>
                        <input name="group3" type="radio" id="ButtonChangeId" class="ButtonChange" value="Button" />
                        <label class="ButtonChange" for="ButtonChangeId">Button</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

EDIT*

I found out it's a Materialize issue. https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2187

Looks like I'm not the only one with this exact same issue either. 

From the above link -"+1 on this. In v.97.7 Chrome doesn't work. Firefox displays the required message, but its no where near the radio buttons."

Comment: Your picture shows that there is more code, could you provide the rest of it

Comment: where is the css?